# Differential nonlinearity in converters

Tags: adc, converter, dnl

I've found multiple sources (eg. [Microchip](https://microchipdeveloper.com/xwiki/bin/view/products/data-converters/adc-specs/adc-dc/adc-differential-non-linearity/), [Analog](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/the-abcs-of-analog-to-digital-converters-how-adc-errors-affect-system-performance.html)) saying something like "An ADC with DNL error less than ±1 LSB guarantees no missing code."

If the DNL is calculated only as a width of the "step" and not with relation to the ideal linear transfer fcn... won't having several wider codes cause a disappearance of some other one?

Unless they only meant to write that DNL > -1 means no output code has 0 width?

Edit: added links.
After reading more into the details in the Analog's description,

> The key is having -1LSB as the low limit.

It seems like my understanding was correct and that just Microchip worded it poorly.

Comment: Please link one of the papers you refer to as multiple sources.

Comment: The wording is correct, since each step is independent, the missing code can come from >+1 or <-1, so ±1 LSB.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat yes, but <+1 does not guarantee no missing codes, only >-1 does

Answer (score 1):

It does guarantee no missing codes because if you run a linear sweep, you won't see any missing codes because they have spaced the voltage bins close enough that you will convert every value and every value is within 1 of the other value, meaning if you do a sweep and subtract every value from the next one there won't be any missing values.

Comment: Sorry, I cant understand anything you wrote. Feels like you went a bit off topic, explaining the effect of DNL or checking of missing codes. I was just asking about the mathematical reasoning, because I wrongly focused on the positive bound instead of negative one, as specified in Analog's doc.